# Flow: annotation of a function variable

Tags: flowtype

What is a proper flow type annotations of variable

```
const a  = x => x
```

using [generics](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/)?

```
const a: (<T> T => T) = x => x
```

is [failing](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzAEMAuMACgB4AVAPjGrAF57qBKZsAD2fq9SA).

Comment: It will be implicitly inferred, why do you need to type it?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Identity function is a simplified example. I'd like to know how to use generics in more complex variable definitions.

Comment: You can try something like `type Foo<T> = T => T; const a: Foo<*> = x => x;` Not sure if this helps

Comment: Thanks. `*` binds the type so it's less universal than generic type: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiccAPACoB8YAvGObdeQNzoDGcAdgM4ZgCGALmJkQ1OgA9GYCey68wAI0FhOAVwC2ivACdaAgBQBGAJSoOPPmxW8dAS04BzffwMByfm7OogA

Comment: Another workaround requires typing `x` as `any`: `const a: (<T> (T) => T) = (x:any) => x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow implicitly types expression `x => x` as `(mixed) => mixed` (according to `flow type-at-pos`). Thus the problem with

```
const a: (<T> T => T) = x => x  // failing
```

is that type of right-hand side (`(mixed) => mixed`) doesn't match to type of left-hand side (`<T> (T) => T`).

Possible solution could be to explicitly set type of right-hand side:

```
const a: (<T> (T) => T) = <U> (x: U): U => x
```

If use of generic wouldn't be required, annotated definition of `a` could look like:

```
const a: (mixed) => mixed = x => x
```